# JAVA SWING - Designing a tree like custom structure

Tags: java, swing

[Mock-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkD0t.png)

Hi everyone, I am trying to develop a tree like structure using swing.

The main part is called Element. Every element has 2 part called MainView and ChildrenView.

MainView holds custom components (components to this view will be added by subclasses of Element). MainView's height is strictly fixed to 50px. Its width is dynamic and extends to end.

ChildrenView holds children Elements like a list. ChildrenView has a left fixed offset, and starts a little bit to the right.

I am having problem with setting the sizes. Element's height is not fixed and scrollablePane is not scrollable.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class DesktopEditor {
    private static final int mainViewHeight = 50;
    static final int padding = 5;
    static final int childOffset = 30;

    public static void main(final String[] arg) {
        openEditor();
    }

    public static void openEditor() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example 1");

        ChildrenView mainPanel = new ChildrenView();

        mainPanel.addChild(new Text().addChild(new Text()));
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());
        mainPanel.addChild(new Text());


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);


        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * here is a example of subClasses of Element
     */
    public static class Text extends Element {
        public Text () {
            super();
            mainView.add(new JTextArea("hello"));
            mainView.add(new Button("hello2"));
        }
    }

    public static class Element extends JPanel {
        SpringLayout layout;

        MainView mainView;
        ChildrenView childView;

        public Element() {
            super();
            setLayout(layout = new SpringLayout());
            // child and mainView
            this.mainView = new MainView();
            this.childView = new ChildrenView();
            add(mainView);
            add(childView);
            // adjust layout
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, mainView, padding, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, mainView, padding, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, mainView, padding, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, mainView, padding + mainViewHeight, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
            //
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, childView, padding + childOffset, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, childView, padding, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, childView, padding, SpringLayout.SOUTH, mainView);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, childView, padding, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);

            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1, mainView.getHeight() + childView.getHeight() + padding *2));
        }

        public Element addChild(Element element) {
            childView.addChild(element);

            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1, mainView.getHeight() + childView.getHeight() + padding *2));
            layout.minimumLayoutSize(this);

            invalidate();
            repaint();

            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class ChildrenView extends JPanel {
        public ChildrenView() {
            super();
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            setBackground(Color.RED);

            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,0));
        }

        public int height() {
            int height = 0;
            for (Component c: getComponents())
                height += c.getHeight();
            return height;
        }

        public Element addChild(Element element) {
            add(element);

            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1, height()));
            invalidate();
            repaint();

            return element;
        }
    }

    public static class MainView extends JPanel {

        public MainView() {
            super();
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, mainViewHeight));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, mainViewHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking how to make a tree using Swing refer to the code below

```
package net.codejava.swing;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
public class TreeExample extends JFrame
{
    private JTree tree;
    public TreeExample()
    {
        //create the root node
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        //create the child nodes
        DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vegetables");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode fruitNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Fruits");
        //add the child nodes to the root node
        root.add(vegetableNode);
        root.add(fruitNode);

        //create the tree by passing in the root node
        tree = new JTree(root);
        add(tree);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("JTree Example");       
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TreeExample();
            }
        });
    }       
}
```